# Retrieve Phone Numbers using Google Contacts API- PHP

Tags: php, google-api

I want to get phone numbers of my Google contacts using Google Contacts API.
But I can't find any tips on it in the internet!
Please help me!
I just can get emails and names of my contacts.
(I'm a Php programmer)

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps you out a bit :)

```html
function curl_file_get_contents($url)
{
 $curl = curl_init();
 $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url); //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE); //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5); //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.

 $contents = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $contents;
}

//with google api make sure you have valid access token with exception.

$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
$xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
$temp = json_decode($xmlresponse,true);
$count = 0; //Setup counter for contacts counting.

foreach($temp['feed']['entry'] as $cnt) {
 $email = $cnt['gd$email']['0']['address']; //As sign email as key here
 if(!empty($email)){
 $c = CheckContact($email); //Check if email exist in database or not 
 if($c<1){ //Email count is less than 1 means this contact is not in database
  $count++; //increment counter
 // $name = isset($cnt['title']['$t'])? $cnt['title']['$t']:'firstname lastname';
  $nn = $cnt['title']['$t'];
  if(!empty($nn)){
   $name = $nn;
  }else{
   $name = "firstname lastname"; //if there is no name for contact 
  }
  $n = explode(' ',$name);  //split name into first and last name for contact
  $f = $n[0];
  $l = $n[1];
  $firstname = isset($f)?$f:'';
  $lastname = isset($l)?$l:'';
  $phone = isset($cnt['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'])? $cnt['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t']:'0000000000'; // Incase phone number is empty and you want to add email into database for this contact
  //echo $firstname." - ".$lastname." - ".$email." - ".$phone."<br/>" ;
  ImportContact($firstname,$lastname,$email,$phone); //Save contact into database.
 } 
 
 
}

}
if($count>1){ 
  //so if saved contacts are more than 1 display success message other wise no contacts are added into database
   ?> 
<div class="alert alert-success"><?php echo $count; ?> contacts imported successfully from gmail.</div>
<?php }else{?>
<div class="alert alert-warning"> No new contact fount for importing.</div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works?  Code dumping without explanation is usually discouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: sorry my bad, i just forget to comment on code. get oauth token with exception and pass to url decode json will be inside temp then you can setup counter to count how many contacts are in the row to be updated, as well you can make a check for existing emails to avoid overwrite rest you can setup as you needed.

Comment: Update your post with the comments